Downloading blobs from azure and unzipping them - troubleshooting code [go]
Have golang code downloading Blobs from Azure storage.  The unzip function throws an error:
"bytes.Reader.ReadAt: negative offsetBlob decompressed contents"
Here is my code? Any suggestions of what could be wrong?
The information passed to the readBlob function in is good - using this code I can print version read and print elements of the actual zip file.
func readBlob(client *azblob.Client, ctx context.Context, containerName string, blobName string) {
    // download the blob
    // will want to do this in the worker pool and not in the main loader thread
    get, err := client.DownloadStream(ctx, containerName, blobName, nil)
    handleError(err)

    downloadedData := bytes.Buffer{}
    retryReader := get.NewRetryReader(ctx, &azblob.RetryReaderOptions{})
    _, err = downloadedData.ReadFrom(retryReader)
    handleError(err)

    err = retryReader.Close()
    handleError(err)

    file, err := decompress(blobName, buff)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error decompressing blob: ", blobName)
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
}

func decompress(blobName string, downloadedData bytes.Buffer) (string, error) {
    // try to decompress as zip
    zipReader, err := zip.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(downloadedData.Bytes()), int64(len(downloadedData.Bytes())))
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    for _, f := range zipReader.File {
    // the next line can add uncomment for troubleshooting and DOES print the right file name -
        does not necessary mean the blob download or the synnex of NewReader is
        perfect - but does validate it somewhat
    // fmt.Println("ffile name in zip file: ", f.Name)
        rc, err := f.Open()  // THIS IS where the error is returned
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
        defer rc.Close()

        decompressedData, err := io.ReadAll(rc)
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
        return string(decompressedData), nil // only care about the first file in the zip file
    }

Things I have tried (and many others):
Added (and removed) a lot of debug printing and a file is definitely downloaded - the decompress function can definitely see the file name BUT it can't 'open' the file inside the zip
I can download the file directly via Azure Storage Explorer and open the zip file with Windows explorer and open the file inside the zip file

After downloding the zip blob from azure
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/storage/azblob"
)

func main() {
    const (
        connectionString = "<connection_string>"
        containerName    = "sample-container"
        blobName         = "ExifToolWrapper-master.zip"
        downloadFile     = "ExifToolWrapper-master.zip"
    )

    // Create a client with the provided connection string
    client, err := azblob.NewClientFromConnectionString(connectionString, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating client:", err)
        return
    }

    // Create or open a local file where we can download the blob
    file, err := os.Create(downloadFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating downloaded file:", err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Download the blob
    _, err = client.DownloadFile(context.TODO(), containerName, blobName, file, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error downloading file:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Blob downloaded successfully!")
}


use the below code is to unzip a file using the standard archive/zip package


package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func unzipSource(source, destination string) error {
    // 1. Open the zip file
    reader, err := zip.OpenReader(source)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer reader.Close()

    // 2. Get the absolute destination path
    destination, err = filepath.Abs(destination)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // 3. Iterate over zip files inside the archive and unzip each of them
    for _, f := range reader.File {
        err := unzipFile(f, destination)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func unzipFile(f *zip.File, destination string) error {
    // 4. Check if file paths are not vulnerable to Zip Slip
    filePath := filepath.Join(destination, f.Name)
    if !strings.HasPrefix(filePath, filepath.Clean(destination)+string(os.PathSeparator)) {
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid file path: %s", filePath)
    }

    // 5. Create directory tree
    if f.FileInfo().IsDir() {
        if err := os.MkdirAll(filePath, os.ModePerm); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return nil
    }

    if err := os.MkdirAll(filepath.Dir(filePath), os.ModePerm); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // 6. Create a destination file for unzipped content
    destinationFile, err := os.OpenFile(filePath, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, f.Mode())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer destinationFile.Close()

    // 7. Unzip the content of a file and copy it to the destination file
    zippedFile, err := f.Open()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer zippedFile.Close()

    if _, err := io.Copy(destinationFile, zippedFile); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    zipFilePath := "C:\\Users\\ExifToolWrapper-master.zip"
    destinationDir := "C:\\Users\\folder\\env"

    err := unzipSource(zipFilePath, destinationDir)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}


